# SQLite - Keep latest 10 rows from 2 tables respectively

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a database with 2 tables named (for example) `TableA` and `TableB`

**Table A , has a column named "someID"**

**Table B , has a column named "tableA_ID"** that relates to TableA.someID field.

I want to keep the last inserted 10 rows of `Table A`, and delete the rest, and do the same on `Table B`, deleting everything but the `10 rows` that match the one's that weren't deleted from `Table A` (latest 10)

I have read that this could be done through `INNER JOINS` but I have little experience with `SQL` and am having an hard time with this.

I have tried the following but cannot delete from the `tableB` the same time I'm deleting from `tableA`

`DELETE FROM TableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableA ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)`

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your IDs are in order,

```
SELECT someID FROM TableA ORDER BY someID DESC LIMIT 10
```

Will give you the latest 10 rows.  Then you can use it as a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE someID NOT IN
(
    SELECT someID FROM TableA ORDER BY someID DESC LIMIT 10
);
DELETE FROM TableB WHERE tableA_ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT someID FROM TableA
);
```

If you want both `DELETE`s to happen at the same time, you have to perform them in a transaction.  How you do that depends on what RDBMS you're using.

In the future, I highly recommend making a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on `TableB` referring to the `someID` column in `TableA`.  If you do that, you should be able to `DELETE CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`.

Comment: Thanks , i'll try this one.
I'm not really experienced in SQL databases and then this bad architecture comes out :)